# Is "When I got back home, did the lights go out?" grammatically correct?

Tags: inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Is the sentence:

> When I got back home, did the lights go out?

grammatically correct, as compared to its inverted form:

> Did the lights go out when I got back home?

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to ELL Stack Exchange. Both your sentences are correct, inverting a sentence in this way is allowed.